# undefined local variable or method from &block when calling instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am getting a `undefined local variable or method` error.

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(my_value, &if_undefine_method)
      @my_value = my_value
      @a = if_undefine_method
   end

  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
     @a.call
  end

  def my_method_to_call_from_block
     'HELLO'
  end
end
```

---

```
a = MyClass.new("some_value") do
     my_method_to_call_from_block
end
```

When I call a missing method:

```
a.a_method_that_does_not_exist
```

the method_missing is called, but I get an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>           3: from (irb):17
>           2: from lib/myruby.rb:22:in `method_missing'
>           1: from (irb):16:in`block in irb_binding' NameError (undefined local variable or method `my_method_to_call_from_block' for
>   main:Object)

How do I reference an instance method from the block I pass, so I prevent the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block isn't part of `MyClass`, it has its own `self` which does not have a `my_method_to_call_from_block` method. Using `@a.call` from inside a method of `MyClass` is no different that calling the block *anywhere else*.

If you want the block to be executed with `self` set to your instance of `MyClass`, you need `instance_eval`:

```
def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
   instance_eval &@a
end
```

Consider the difference:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(&block)
      @block = block
   end

  def default_self
    @block.call
  end

  def myclass_self
    instance_eval &@block
  end
end


a = MyClass.new do
  p self
end

a.default_self # main

a.myclass_self # <MyClass:0x00007f8da68da348 @block=#<Proc:0x00007f8da68da320@test.rb:16>>
```

Comment: Why do I need the & in &@block?

Comment: `instance_eval` expects a block argument, not a regular positional argument: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval. It's the difference between a positional argument, `def foo(x)`, and a block argument, `def bar(&block)`. You would invoke `foo(x)` or `block(&x)` to pass a proc in `x` to either method.